# Replacing Empty fields with good data based on other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
    A   B   C  Value
0   10  aa  MN     5
1   10  aa  NaN    6
2   12  bb  MN     5
3   13  cc  BK     7
4   13  cc  Nan    8
5   14  cc  SI     8
```

I am trying to clean the date so that where columns A and B are identical it will assign C to the matching value combine the rows and sum C

```
    df:
    A   B   C  Value
0   10  aa  MN     11
1   12  bb  MN     5
2   13  cc  BK     15
3   14  cc  SI     8
```

Should be noted that only column C has `NaN` values. All three values should make unique groups but are not exclusive to there group.
How would I do this in my `Jupyterbook`?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, so please share your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or update your question with other effort you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using ffill() and then group_by and sum() to get the table I needed

```
df = df.ffill()
df = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).Value.sum().reset_index()
df_incident_local_count.head()

        df:
    A   B   C  Value
0   10  aa  MN     11
1   12  bb  MN     5
2   13  cc  BK     15
3   14  cc  SI     8
```

I don't know where the comment went but someone else recommend ffill(). Credit goes to that stranger.

Answer (score 0):

Give aggregation functions for 'c' and 'value'. Then aggregate by group.

```
agg_func = {'c': 'max', 'value':'sum'}
df_new = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg(agg_func)
```